# How to create formula for this lookup table

Tags: least-squares

I have a lookup table.

**$X$ values are:**

$\{230, 220, 210, 200, 190, 180, 170, 160, 150, 140, 130, 120, 110, 100, 90, 80\}$

**$Y$ values are:**

$\{2590, 2590, 2590, 2580, 2540, 2460, 2260, 1870, 1240, 1040, 960, 800, 680, 480, 360, 160\}$

[This is the excel graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/481BL.png)

I tried to create a formula using least square approximation. However, the accuracy is quite bad. Also I tried to split the data into $3$ different datas where the curve looks like linear and tried the same method. I could not get good solution.

I did not study math but I try to learn math methods to solve my problem. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Please give full details about the source of the problem.

Comment: Another question is : what do you plan to do with the results ? Interpolation ?

Comment: I need a function which gives y result when x is given to it. My problem is accuracy. Accuracy is not good.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I want the function to estimate the result. For example I want the result when x is 93.

Comment: So, if you want to compute for any value of $x$ such that $80 \leq x \leq 230$, you face interpolation. Forget regression and formula.

Comment: For $x=93$, $y=397.12$ for me